# VPS domain name configuration

Tags: windows, https, jenkins, vps, repository

I have a VPS and a domain name from OVH.
On my VPS, I installed Artifactory (the VPS is also its binary repository) and Jenkins (the VPS is also its slave) with the build tools I need.

Jenkins and Artifactory are accessible through HTTP following this pattern :
`http://my.domain.name.com:port_number`.

My question is, how can make it possible to use instead :
`http://my.domain.name.com/jenkins` or `http://jenkins.my.domain.name.com` (for both Jenkins and Artifactory of course)?

Also, how can I secure the access (force HTTPS connections and prevent using HTTP and other ports)?

Note : The VPS is running under Windows Server 2016.

Comment: what you are looking for is called a reverse proxy: https://www.google.com/search?&q=web+server+reverse+proxy  reverse proxies can handle both ssl termination and delegating requests to back-end services

Comment: @jayhendren Is a reverse proxy the same thing as a reverse DNS (I guess no)?

Comment: *Is a reverse proxy the same thing as a reverse DNS?* - They are two completely separate things and have no relation to each other.

Comment: @jayhendren Thanks. Maybe you should make a real answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make it possible to use `http://my.domain.name.com/jenkins` or `http://jenkins.my.domain.name.com` instead (for both Jenkins and Artifactory of course)?

As noted in the comments, you will want to set up a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). A reverse proxy will take incoming web requests for e.g.:

```
http://jenkins.my.domain.name.com
```

and forward them to the proper destination:

```
http://my.domain.name.com:port_number
```

> I have a VPS and a domain name from OVH. The VPS is running under Windows Server 2016.

Windows Server 2016 typically runs IIS 10, so you are likely going to need [URL Rewrite 2.1](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and [Application Request Routing (ARR) 3.0](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) to reverse proxy web requests. Depending on the Windows Server 2016 image your VPS provides, these may or may not already be installed.

**Installing URL Rewrite and ARR Manually**

- Use the web installer links given above or the [Microsoft Wep Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).
- Alternately, there are [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) packages available for [URL Rewrite](https://chocolatey.org/packages/UrlRewrite) and [ARR](https://chocolatey.org/packages/iis-arr), as well.
- The Web Platform Installer is available under the *IIS Manager* → *Management* section, if installed:

  *ex. Web Platform Installer*

  [image: IIS Manager Console - Web Platform Installer Icon]
- URL Rewrite should generally be installed before ARR.
- If you encounter issues installing URL Rewrite, [you may need to change the IIS version number temporarily](https://www.saotn.org/install-iis-url-rewrite-module-windows-server-2016-iis-10/). However, this should be fixed in current versions of URL Rewrite.

> How can I secure the access (force HTTPS connections and prevent using HTTP and other ports)?

You can use an SSL certificate and bind e.g.:

```
http://jenkins.my.domain.name.com
```

solely to port 443 (HTTPS). This would prevent any access from port 80. That is, the URL would become (only) `https://jenkins.my.domain.name.com`.

Regarding blocking access from other ports, you would likely want to firewall `http://my.domain.name.com:port_number` from outside access and use `localhost:port_number` for your reverse proxy entries instead.

---

## Examples

---

***Prerequisites***

*The following examples assume that:*

- *You have already create new HTTP subdomains in IIS e.g.:*

  ```
  http://jenkins.my.domain.name.com
  http://artifactory.my.domain.name.com
  ```
- *You have updated your domain name provider with new A records for your subdomains and you can reach them successfully in a browser.*
- *URL Rewrite and ARR are both installed on your system.*

---

**Securing A Subdomain**

For these examples, I am assuming you do not have any SSL certificates available. While I demonstrate one way to install an SSL certificate below, be aware that the actual steps in obtaining and installing a certificate may be quite different depending on who issues that certificate.

**Let's Encrypt and ZeroSSL**

[Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is a free SSL Certificate Authority which issues SSL certificates valid for 3 months before (free) renewal is necessary. They issue certificates through an online API available from a number of sites and command line utilities, including ones provided by [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/).

While ZeroSSL does have a web interface for obtaining/renewing Let's Encrypt certificates, I am going to focus on [Crypt-LE](https://github.com/do-know/Crypt-LE), the command line utility provided by ZeroSSL.

**Getting A Certificate**

After getting a copy of Crypt-LE from the [Do-Know/ZeroSSL GitHub repository](https://github.com/do-know/Crypt-LE/releases) and ensuring that you can reach your subdomain(s) in a browser, run Crypt-LE (`le32.exe` or `le64.exe`) with the following options:

- `--key C:\path\to\folder\account_key`
- `--email "me@my.domain.name.com"`
- `--csr C:\path\to\folder\jenkins.csr`
- `--csr-key C:\path\to\folder\jenkins.key`
- `--crt C:\path\to\folder\jenkins.crt`
- `--domains "jenkins.my.domain.name.com"`
- `--path C:\path\to\subdomain\webroot\.well-known\acme-challenge`
- `--generate-missing`
- `--unlink`
- `--export-pfx "password"`

In this instance:

- `C:\path\to\folder` can be anywhere you wish to store any files produced by Crypt-LE.
- `--key C:\path\to\folder\account_key` is a path to a Let's Encrypt private account key. If you have an existing key, you would use e.g.:

  ```
  --key C:\path\to\folder\account_key\lets_encrypt.key
  ```
- If you have never used Let's Encrypt before, `--generate-missing` should produce a new account key for you.
- `--email` is technically optional (I believe) and is only used for new certificates.
- `--csr`, `--csr-key` and `--crt` define the locations/file names for your certificate signing request (`.csr`) and issued PEM format certificate files (`.key`, `.crt`). Again, these should all be created by `--generate-missing` (assuming they don't already exist).
- `--domains` contains the subdomain you wish to register (e.g. `jenkins.my.domain.name.com`).
- `--path C:\path\to\subdomain\webroot\` should be the path to an IIS subdomain web root, not to Jenkins or Artifactory themselves. `.well-known\acme-challenge` needs to remain exactly as it is.
- `--export-pfx "password"` exports a `.pfx` file suitable for importing into IIS. `"password"` is a password of your choice used when importing the `.pfx` file into IIS.

By default, the commands above are run on test servers for Let's Encrypt, which do not issue valid certificates.

Once you are happy that your Crypt-LE command is working as desired, erase any generated `.csr`, `.key` and `.crt` files and add `--live` to the end of your other options above. Be aware that while you can erase any generated Let's Encrypt account key (the first option), this isn't necessary and you can specify the path to it in any subsequent commands you issue.

**Installing PFX Files**

Once you have a valid certificate contained in a `.pfx` file, you are ready to import it into IIS.

1. Open the IIS Manager. At the server level, select *Server Certificates*:

   *ex. IIS Server Certificates Option*

   [image: IIS Server Certificates Option Screenshot]
2. Under the *Server Certificates* pane, select `Import...` from *Actions*:

   *ex. IIS Import Action*

   [image: IIS Import Action Screenshot]
3. In the *Import Certificate* dialog, provide the path to your `.pfx` file and the password from `--export-pfx "password"`:

   *ex. Import Certificate Dialog*

   [image: Import Certificate Dialog Screenshot]
4. After clicking `OK` (above), you should be taken back to the main *Server Certificates* pane and see a new entry for your certificate:

   *ex. Installed PFX Certificate*

   [image: Installed PFX Certificate]
5. You may need to restart your server after this to ensure the certificate is recognized correctly.

**Binding SSL Certificates**

To bind your installed SSL certificate to your subdomain, do the following:

1. In the IIS Manager, select your site and select `Bindings` from *Actions*:

   *ex. Site Bindings Action*

   [image: Site Bindings Action Screenshot]
2. In the *Site Bindings* dialog, click `Add...`:

   *ex. Site Bindings Dialog*

   [image: Site Bindings Dialog Screenshot]
3. In the *Add Site Binding* dialog, select `https` from the protocol `Type` dropdown menu and select the appropriate subdomain SSL certificate from the `SSL Certificate` dropdown menu:

   *ex. Add Site Binding Dialog*

   [image: Add Site Binding Dialog Screenshot]
4. After clicking `OK` (above), you should be taken back to the *Site Bindings* dialog and see a new entry for your HTTPS binding:

   *ex. Site Bindings Dialog*

   [image: Site Bindings Dialog Screenshot]
5. You may need to restart your site after this to ensure your HTTPS settings are recognized correctly.

You should now be able to use e.g.:

```
https://jenkins.my.domain.name.com
```

to access your subdomain. If you want to entirely block access from port 80 (HTTP), simply remove the HTTP 80 binding. Note, however, you will likely need to re-add it when renewing any Let's Encrypt certificate. Also, this obviously does not address blocking e.g.:

```
http://my.domain.name.com:port_number
```

in the Windows firewall.

---

**Reverse Proxy**

To set up e.g. `https://jenkins.my.domain.name.com` as a reverse proxy, do the following:

1. Open the IIS Manager. Under your site, select *URL Rewrite*:

   *ex. URL Rewrite Option*

   [image: URL Rewrite Option Screenshot]
2. In the main *URL Rewrite* pane, select `Add Rule(s)...` from *Actions*:

   *ex. Add Rule(s) Action*

   [image: Add Rule(s) Action Screenshot]
3. In the *Add Rule(s)* dialog, select `Reverse Proxy` from the *Inbound and Outbound Rules* template section:

   - ex. Add Rule(s) Dialog*

   [image: Add Rule(s) Dialog Screenshot]
4. In template, use `localhost:port` for the *Add Reverse Proxy Rules* `Inbound Rules` server field. The port should correspond to the port of whichever service (i.e. Jenkins or Artifactory) you wish to use:

   *ex. Add Reverse Proxy Rules Dialog*

   [image: Add Reverse Proxy Rules Dialog Screenshot]
5. You may need to restart your site after this to ensure your rewrite rules are recognized correctly.

You should now be able to access e.g. Jenkins at ex.:

```
https://jenkins.my.domain.name.com
```

You may or may not need to enable the `Outbound` section of the rewrite rules above. However, I would thoroughly test access first with them disabled. It's also probably worth mentioning that you should keep `Enable SSL Offloading` checked as a rule.